# Plotting secondary x axis in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

How can I plot a secondary x axis with my custom labels in Octave below the standard x axis?

The best would be to have a look like "ployxx" graph, but this does not exist in Octave.

```
x=1:7
y=sin(x)
plot(x,y)
ht=text(1,-1.1,"22,150,160,150,140,150,22);
```

Comment: You can certainly do it by accessing [graphics structure objects](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Introduction-to-Graphics-Structures.html). See, for example [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/317-plotxx-m), and [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2013-04/msg00070.html). Note MATLAB code should work, as most of those functions are available in Octave.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by `plotxx` you mean something like the example given [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/317-plotxx-m), then this is how I would draw that:

```
% Create the data
  Salinity    = linspace( 32, 34, 100 );
  Temperature = linspace( 0 , 10, 100 );
  Depth_S     = linspace( 0, -100, 100 );
  Depth_T     = 50 * log( linspace( 0, 1, 100 ) );

% Explicitly create two axes
  Ax_S = axes();
  Ax_T = axes();

% Plot the two graphs into their respective axes
  plot( Ax_S, Salinity   , Depth_S, 'r', 'linewidth', 3 );
  plot( Ax_T, Temperature, Depth_T, 'b', 'linewidth', 3 );

% Set the axes to the same position, and change xaxis and yaxis locations,
 % colors, limits and other properties as desired
  set( Ax_S, 'position'     , [ 0.15, 0.15, 0.70, 0.70 ],
             'units'        , 'normalized'          ,
             'box'          , 'off'                 ,
             'fontsize'     , 16                    ,
             'linewidth'    , 2                     ,
             'xaxislocation', 'top'                 ,
             'xcolor'       , 'r'                   ,
             'yaxislocation', 'left'                ,
             'xlim'         , [ 32  , 34  ]         ,
             'ylim'         , [ -100, 0   ]         ,
             'xlabel'       , 'Salinity'            ,
             'ylabel'       , 'Depth (m)'             );

% For the axes on the 'top' of the stack, additionally make the background
 % color 'transparent' (by setting it to 'none')
  set( Ax_T, 'position'     , [ 0.15, 0.15, 0.70, 0.70 ],
             'units'        , 'normalized'          ,
             'box'          , 'off'                 ,
             'fontsize'     , 16                    ,
             'linewidth'    , 2                     ,
             'xaxislocation', 'bottom'              ,
             'xcolor'       , 'b'                   ,
             'yaxislocation', 'right'               ,
             'xlim'         , [ 0   , 10 ]          ,
             'ylim'         , [ -100, 0  ]          ,
             'xlabel'       , 'Temperature (C)'     ,
             'ylabel'       , 'Depth (m)'           ,
             'color'        , 'none'                   );

% Ensure the right 'stacking' order by calling the axes objects again in the
 % right order (from bottom to top)
  axes( Ax_S );
  axes( Ax_T );
```

[image]